# when removing multiple images in an image file is not selected with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My project has multiple image upload space. I choose 4 pictures. I have selected one of the pictures removed when the file is not selected what is the reason?

```
                    <div class="aupload">
                        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='admin/images/upload.png') }}" class="uploadImage" alt="">
                        <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn form-control btn-default">Kaydet</button>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
            $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
              var files = e.target.files,
                filesLength = files.length;
              for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                var f = files[i]
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                  var file = e.target;
                  $("<div class=\"preview\">" +
                    "</span><img class=\"uploadImg\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
                    "<span class=\"remove\"><i class=\"fa fa-times\"></i>" +
                    "</div>").insertAfter("#files");
                  $(".remove").click(function(){
                    $(this).parent(".preview").remove();
                    $('#files').val("");
                  });    
                });
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
              }
            });
          } else {
            alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
          }
        });
    </script>
```

What I want to do is: clicking the remove button will remove the uploaded photo and reduce the number of files selected. I'd appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: removing files are working properly without decreasing the file count, Am I right ?

Comment: Exactly. Yes true @SilentCoder